# Window comparator diode direction

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit, schematics, comparator

What happens if we reverse the configuration of diode in window comparator? Will it remain a window comparator?

[image: circuit of window comparator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work at all in this case. The output of the opamp goes high, and the diodes turn on when the output goes high. The diodes are in an "or" configuration allowing either of the comparators to pull the 4049 high (towards 5V).

If the diodes were reversed, very little current would flow and the circuit would not function as intended and the input of the 4049 would always remain low.

Comment: The circuit won't work in either case as shown - there needs to be a pull-down resistor at the input of the 4049 in the original circuit. If you reverse the diodes there needs to be a pull-up resistor. Without a resistor the input to the 4049 is indeterminate when the diodes are not conducting.

Comment: I just assumed that it had a low impedance input, but on checking it looks like the input current is in the uA range, so it would need a pulldown. (or you could wait a long long time.)

Comment: the input is normal CMOS, the only current is leakage and it is undefined which rail it leaks to. It could leak to ground or the positive rail or anywhere in-between depending upon the leakage of the individual devices.